# Creating animated plot for 2 2D arrays in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I have two 2D numpy arrays of data (x and y). One of the arrays is the x values and the other is the y values.
each row in the arrays represents the single frame data.

I want to create an animated plot that will take the first row of the first array and plot it against the first row of the other array, and continue to do this along the different rows while animating.

Also, I want to execute it for viewing inside the Jupyter notebook.

I've tried to do it with line plot - but it doesn't work:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.set_xlim( (220,300) )
ax.set_ylim( (0,1000)  )
ax.axes.invert_yaxis()

fig.suptitle('Something')
ax.set_xlabel('Temperature')
ax.set_ylabel('Pressure')

x0 = x[0,:]
y0 = y[0,:]

line, = ax.plot(x0, y0, '-o')

def animate(i):
    line.set_xdata(x[i,:])
    line.set_ydata(y[i,:])
    return line

anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, frames=30, interval=10, blit=True)

HTML(anim.to_html5_video())
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: 'Line2D' object is not iterable
```

I think that there is another way to do it instead of Line plot, but I didn't find it yet.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When saving, `blit=True` does not make any sense. Remove that. When `blit=False`, there is no need to return anything, you may hence also remove the return statement completely.

If you want to run this animation inside a jupyter notebook with the `%matplotlib notebook` backend or outside a notebook, you may use `blit=True`. In that case, return a tuple from the animation,

```
return line,
```

Comment: Well as said, rather opt for removing `blit=True` from the animation, as it is just superfluous when creating a HTML5 animation in jupyter.